# PySpark regexp_replace does not work as expected for the following pattern

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using spark streaming to consume from a topic and make transformations on the data.
Amidst these is a regex replacement.
The `regexp_replace` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` is not replacing the following pattern (I tested it beforehand using regex101.com, `re` from python, etc):

`df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', '([A-Za-z]+=[^,]*?)(\[[A-Z,a-z,0-9]+\])',r'$1'))`

this is a snippet of the record:

```
{someVersion=8.3.2-hmg-dev, someUnitName=IB, someMessage=Test. [BL056], someOrigin=MOBILE, someStatus=TEST, duration=3500,
```

and This is the "target" of the regex pattern:
 `someMessage=Test. [BL056]`

It should match the entire target and split in two groups, and replace it by the first group matched alone (as by `r'$1'`).

These are also patterns that didn't work:

- `df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', '([A-Za-z]+=[^,]*?)',''))`
- `df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', '(\[[A-Z,a-z,0-9]+\])',''))`

This worked:

- `df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', 'someMessage=Test. [BL056]',''))`

Why is this happening? Are there specificities to the spark regex engine?
What would be the right pattern for what I'm trying to do?

Examples and the entire script is listed below:

This is an example value of the "value" column:

```
{someVersion=8.3.2-hmg-dev, someUnitName=IB, someMessage=Test. [BL056], someOrigin=MOBILE, someStatus=TEST, duration=3500, someNumber=9872329, someAppOrigin=APP_PADRAO, someId=c3ASAUSQTiWvl_YA9DYpDV:APA91bGfVcLNNGL20hfmaDDS0D8TuzJDuCjj4tgbRNcJcYASIBRVEE2FnA4exnE4ZWTuupRX7FQkdcJiMWkNEatk8lktkFcpR7P7mehb4r_SVnabIabGInjagGZ6pGyweDkxW2JUGK8g, someType=00001, someOriginOpen=null, someOS=null, eventSubType=TESTLOGON, someToken=, ip=error, somePair=0.4220043,-1.084015, eventType=SUCESSO, someMag=aWg4V01qSxDMjAvWmlEWGJ6aExnc2nZJbWZVPQ==, macAddress=33d94a3f7d2f8aff, someJSON=\{"ip":"error","hostname":null,"type":null,"concode":null,"continent":null,"country":null,"country_name":null,"code":null,"name":null,"city":null,"zip":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"anotherJSON":{"id":null,"capital":null,"languages":null,"flag":null,"flag_emoji":null,"flag_emoji_unicode":null,"calling_code":null,"is_eu":null},"time_zone":\{"id":null,"current_time":null,"gmt_offset":null,"code":null,"is_daylight_saving":null},"currency":\{"code":null,"name":null,"plural":null,"symbol":null,"symbol_native":null},"connection":\{"asn":null,"isp":null},"security":\{"is_proxy":null,"proxy_type":null,"is_crawler":null,"crawler_name":null,"crawler_type":null,"is_tor":null,"threat_level":null,"threat_types":null}}, organization=IBPF, codigoCliente=440149, device=Android SDK built for x86, eventDate=6/1/20 4:03 PM}
```

This is the whole code:

````py
import re
import json
import pyhocon
import fastavro
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


def decode(msg, schema):
    bytes_io = BytesIO(msg)
    bytes_io.seek(5)
    msg = fastavro.schemaless_reader(bytes_io, schema)
    return msg


def parse(msg):
    conf = pyhocon.ConfigParser.parse(msg)
    msg_converter = pyhocon.tool.HOCONConverter.to_json(conf)
    msg = json.loads(msg_converter)
    return msg


def get_schema(registry_url,topic):
    URL = f'\{registry_url}/subjects/\{topic}/versions/latest'
    response = requests.get(url=URL, verify=False)
    subject = response.json()
    schema_id = subject['id']
    schema = json.loads(subject['schema'])
    return [schema_id, schema]


schema_id, schema = get_schema(registry_url=SCHEMA_REGISTRY,topic=SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC)
spark.udf.register('decode',lambda value: decode(value,schema))
spark.udf.register('parse',parse)
spark.readStream \
 .format('kafka') \
 .option('subscribe', SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC) \
 .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
 .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', HOST) \
 .option('kafka.security.protocol', 'SSL') \
 .option('kafka.ssl.key.password', KEYSTORE_PASSWORD) \
 .option('kafka.ssl.keystore.location', KEYSTORE_PATH) \
 .option('kafka.ssl.truststore.location', KEYSTORE_PATH) \
 .option('kafka.ssl.keystore.password', KEYSTORE_PASSWORD) \
 .option('kafka.ssl.truststore.password', KEYSTORE_PASSWORD) \
 .load() \
 .selectExpr(f'decode(value) as value') \
 .withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', '([A-Za-z]+=[^,]*?)(\[[A-Z,a-z,1-9]+\])','$1'))\
 .writeStream \
 .format('console') \
 .option('truncate', 'false') \
 .start()
```
````

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and show us the _exact_ input text, along with what you are trying to extract.  If the data isn't really surrounded by `{...}` brackets, then remove those brackets, they aren't helping to get your point across here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

If you want only the output use regexp_extract and if you want to replace it use regexp replace

the working regex for me are:

```
df.select(regexp_extract('value','someMessage=\w+\.\ \[\w+\]',0)).show(2,False)
#and
df.select(regexp_extract('value','someMessage=(.*)]',0)).show(2,False)

+-------------------------------------------+
|val                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
|someMessage=Test. [BL056]                  |
|someMessage=Test. [BL056]                  |
+-------------------------------------------+


And if you want to replace use this

df.select(regexp_replace('value','someMessage=(.*)]',''))
```